# how to download all the URL image content listed in .CSV in google colab?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, url, google-colaboratory

I have a CSV file. It contains the product ID, product category, and the URL of the product image.

This is the code I tried in the google colab.

```
import csv
import request

with open('product.csv') as csvfile:
    csvrows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvrows:
        _product_id = row[0]
        catagory = row[1]
        image_url = row[2]
        print(image_url)
        result = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            image = result.raw.read()
            open(product.csv,"wb").write(image)
```

I need to download all the information with product image in google colab for further steps.

```
Invalid syntax Image_url. Did you mean http:\\image_url?
```

Comment: so what is the current output or error?  Also, include sample data file for problem replication.

Comment: I will edit in Q

Comment: what does `image_url` contain?  check the result of `print(image_url)` and see if meets the syntax requirement for next statement `requests.get`.  if still not working, indicate what image_url string shows.

Comment: The problem got solved! added 'http:\\link' It's just there are too many images so colab taking time to load.